# Weatherforcasting for numbers and primes.

Tags: number-theory

This question is inspired from the video "FamousMathProbs1: Factoring large numbers into primes" by Wildberger and from this [article](http://nrich.maths.org/1422) about Galois theory.

---

So Galois theory is about radicals and polynomials. For example, does there exist a radical (a formula made from basic operations +, -, $\times$... that evaluates the root of a polynomial with rational coefficients) for a given polynomial.

It turns out that for polynomials of degree 5 and more, it doesn't exist! We can check that by computer.

Thanks to the fundamental theorem of galois theory, we have a deep idea of why radicals don't exist for polynomials of degree 5 and more. And basically, a polynomial must satisfy some "solvability" arguments to have a radical.

In the same sense, I was wondering, does there exist for every number something which will tell us if that number when factored into primes will give us for example a product of 2, 3 and 17 and not 2, 3 and 19 for example? Do such arguments exist?

Thank you and Happy PiDay!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but for example if a number ends with a 5 or a 0, then 5 must be a prime factor in that number. If it does not, then 5 is not a prime factor in that number. Something like that?

Comment: @naslundx What I really mean: Take as an example a polynomial of degree 2, how do we know it has real solutions? We simply compute its determinant $\Delta=b^2-4ac$. if we get $\Delta<0$ it doesn't have real solutions. That's the kind of arguments I'm searching for but instead of polynomials, we just have numbers!

Comment: @naslundx yes something like that apparently. but I doubt that exists for every prime. Euler said about primes,`"primes something something mystery something something impenetrable for human minds"` or something like that

Comment: @user135823 So you have a number, say 176. What would you like to find out? Not its prime factorization?

Comment: @naslundx I want to know something that could determine for me the prime factors of 176.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no** closed formula for calculating the prime factors of a given number $n$. There are algorithms for finding that out though, for example trying to divide $n$ with all primes  $\leq \sqrt{n}$ and if the remainder is an integer, we know that that prime is a factor in $n$. Or if we know some/all divisors, we can start by prime factorizing them.

Of course, for large $n$, this quickly becomes a really heavy computation, even for our fastest computers. This is partly why different encryption systems (such as [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA)) are safe - it's simply too computationally difficult to prime factorize a huge number (for now).

Quantum computers, if they become a practical reality, would do this much faster though, for example using [Shor's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm).